# Discrete Mathematics - Intersection of a collection of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $ B_n $ = (0,$\frac{1}{n}]$ for all n ∈ N.

(a) Find $ ⋂_{n=1}^∞ = B_n $ and

(b) For each n ∈ N, find $ ⋂_{k=1}^n = B_k $

I know that the answer to (a) is ∅ but for (b) I think that when n ≠ 1, the answer is (0,$\frac{1}{n}]$ because n ≠ ∞ as ∞ ∉ N.

Am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a), as you said the answer is indeed $\emptyset$ due to the following:

Assuming it is nonempty, let $r \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n $. It follows that $0 < r \leq \frac{1}{n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. By the Archimedean Principle, there is an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n_0} < r$. But we also have $r \leq \frac{1}{n_0}$ (by assumption), a contradiction. Thus the intersection is empty.

For part b) you are also correct, but for it's also true for $n=1$. That is, $\bigcap_{k=1}^{n} B_k  = B_n$. We can prove this by induction if you want the details.

Certainly for $n = 2$, 
$$\bigcap_{k=1}^{2} B_k = B_1 \cap B_2 = (0, 1] \cap (0, \frac{1}{2}] = (0, \frac{1}{2}] = B_2$$

Suppose this holds for all such intersections up to $n$ and let us consider the intersection of $n + 1$:
$$ \bigcap_{k=1}^{n+1} B_k = \bigcap_{k=1}^{n} B_k \cap B_{n+1}$$
By the induction hypothesis, the above intersection is simply 
$$ B_n \cap B_{n+1} = (0, \frac{1}{n}] \cap (0, \frac{1}{n+1}] = (0, \frac{1}{n+1}] = B_{n+1}$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, but it's true for $n = 1$ as well. The key is to notice that the $B_k$ are nested, i.e.
$$B_1 \supset B_2 \supset B_3 \supset \cdots,$$
thus
$$\bigcap_{k=1}^{n}B_k = B_n = (0,1/n].$$